# Issues converting JMeter JMX files from JMeter 2.10 to jMeter 3.0

Tags: jmeter

Error:
An error occurred while copying node:
Local class incompatible.SerialVersion UID=240 LocalclassSerialVersion UID=241

Comment: Please describe what you are doing to get this error.

Comment: Actually I am trying to open Jmx scripts written in JMeter 2.10 into JMeter 3.0 . I am finding those exceptions while I am opening those jmx files in JMeter 3.0.